# connecting commands

Tags: macros, diagrams, eps, svg, export

Can I connect commands so that one is automatically called before another?
I have for example:

```
\newcommand{\convertsvg}[1]{%
\immediate\write18%
{inkscape -D -z --file=figs/#1.svg %
--export-eps=figs/#1.eps}%
}
```

now every time that I want to place a svg-picture I do:

```
\convertsvg{examplepicture}
\centering\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{examplepicture}
```

How can I connect this two, such that \convertsvg is called every time before I do the /includegraphics?

I tried it like this:

```
\newcommand{\includegraphicssvg}[1]{%
\immediate\write18%
{inkscape -D -z --file=figs/#1.svg %
--export-eps=figs/#1.eps}%
\includegraphics{#1.eps}%
}
```

But I got problems with the Optional arguments from \includegraphics. So it is not possible to do this:

```
\includegraphicssvg[width=\columnwidth]{examplepicture}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `\newcommand{\includegraphicssvg}[2][]{%` where `#1` will be used for the  optional argument designed for `\includegraphics` and `#2` means the file name. More control can be done with `\NewDocumentCommand` from `xparse` package

Comment: i think you don't want a `%` immediately after `\write18`.  it may not be harmful in this case, but usually where a number is being read, tex will continue to read until it finds something that is *not* a number.  leaving a space will cut off the parsing, which is much safer.

Answer (score 2):

Now I have:

```
\newcommand{\includegraphicssvg}[2][]{%
\immediate\write18%
{inkscape -D -z --file=figs/#2.svg %
--export-eps=figs/#2.eps}%
\includegraphics[#1]{#2.eps}%
}
```

Very happy with this solution!